# Standard / Boost facility for advancing an iterator until either the end or a delimiter is hit?

Tags: c++, iterator

The standard library provides `std::advance`, but that only advances an iterator to a given offset.

Writing that algorithm yourself is pretty trivial:

```
template<class Iter, class T>
void advance_until(Iter& it, Iter end, T const& delim){
  while(it != end && *it != delim)
    ++it;
}
```

Or even:

```
template<class Iter, class T>
void unsafe_advance_until(Iter& it, T const& delim){
  while(*it != delim)
    ++it;
}
```

Which would more closely model the way `std::advance` behaves.

Usage example:

```
std::string s("hello world!");
std::string::iterator it(s.begin());
advance_until(it, s.end(), 'w');
//unsafe_advance_until(it, 'w');
if(it != s.end())
  std::cout << *it << '\n'; // prints 'w'
```

But maybe there's already something like that in the standard library or Boost, so I thought I'd ask away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is commonly known as `std::find()`:

```
std::string::iterator it = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), 'w');

if (it == s.end()) { /* not found */ }
else               { /* found *it */ }
```

Successive items can be found through a loop:

```
while (it != s.end())
{
  // ...
  ++it; // always valid
  it = std::find(it, s.end(), 'w');
}
```

Comment: "To miss the forest for the trees"... well, that facepalm hurt. :|

Comment: Btw, could one shove that increment into the `find`? Theoretically the function call introduces a sequence point, so there shouldn't be any UB, right?

Comment: @Xeo: I was wondering that, too, but I wasn't sure. This could be a `for` loop: `for (auto it = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), 'w'), end = s.end(); it != end; it = std::find(++it, s.end(), 'w') { }`???

Comment: Oh, even `it = ++it` shouldn't introduce UB, so long `it` is a user defined type with overloaded `operator++`, since that operator should introduce a sequence point. Wasn't `++` only UB when you use primitive types?

Comment: That would just be a no-op, wouldn't it? I.e. both sides have the same value, and the assignment should be checking for self-assignment. Anyway, you don't know that the iterator isn't just a typedef for a raw pointer, so perhaps that's not a good idea...

Comment: Ugh, lets stop this, thinking about UB in the morning makes my head hurt... :(

Comment: @KerrekSB "_and the assignment should be checking for self-assignment._" actually, most assignment operators don't need to check for self-assignment (well known exception is `shared_ptr`)